# removing the white border in material 3d viewport when selecting alpha blend or alpha clip

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, transparency

i'm trying to get these leaves to show correctly in the 3d viewport (not render) with the transparency applied and no white border around the leaves, i had to choose alpha clip or alpha blend to get the transparency to show up in the 3d viewport, but there is this annoying white border around the leaves, any way to fix this? FYI this node setup looks normal in render mode but i'm don't want to render that way right now.

[image]

Comment: On the lower right corner of your picture there is an alpha scale (above the Alpha Blend drop down menu) decrease its value!

Comment: that doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

i figured out an acceptable workaround for my purposes, i changed the color in the transparency node from white to a very dark green and its good enough for me

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t need a hack. Your alpha format is not being interpreted correctly, or Blender has yet another alpha issue. Worth finding the actual issue here.