# Eevee how to render without black boxes in textures?

Tags: rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

How cam I get rid of the black color from my texture in render? I believe it's possible.

Here's what I have:
[image]
And here's what I need to look like(I switched to texture paint mod and black dissapeared, **how can I achieve that for the render result?**):
[image]

If I change it to Alpha Blend it seems very transparent, so you could barely see it
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alpha Channel in Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/alpha-channel-in-eevee)

This has already been answered here. You have to switch your Material Settings Blend mode to Alpha.

Edit : This goes hand to hand with this kind of node setup of course :
[image]

Comment: They look very transparent now, I can barely see it

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I've already found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131971/removing-the-white-border-in-material-3d-viewport-when-selecting-alpha-blend-or

Comment: And it works prefectly